# Skype Not installing in ubuntu 12.XX

Tags: 12.04, skype

I use Ubuntu 12.04 (multiarch) 64-bit. I need to install skype but not able to install.

I get the error. Screen shot attached.

Also how can i update to Ubuntu 14.XX - 64-bit?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a screenshot? could you post the error?

Comment: In regards to updating Ubuntu please have look at this question:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: Skype is also in the "Canonical Partners" repository, so after activating this package source in your system settings, you should be able to install it simply by executing the command `sudo apt-get install skype`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Just download the `.deb` file from Skype website (the following link)

   [Skype for Linux](http://www.skype.com/en/download-skype/skype-for-computer/)
2. Put the file in your home directory from Downloads.
3. Suppose the file name is `skype-version.deb`, then run the following command in the terminal

   `sudo dpkg -i skype-version.deb`
4. Give your password.